# .htaccess file Wordpress RewriteRule Block Rearrange to the top

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I was having issues (401 error) trying to reach my website via rest API. I moved the Wordpress block in my .htaccess file to the top and now my website is reachable. This is the first block that I now have in my .htaccess file?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Do I need to combine the two lines of the RewriteRule lines like this? Does it change anything functionally?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Prior to me making any changes, the first block in the .htaccess file was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

So by moving the "Wordpress block" it just adds the one line `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to combine the two lines

You certainly don't "need" to combine those two lines.

It will probably make no difference to accessing your rest API if you do.

#### A single, combined directive

By combining those two directives, as you have done, will mean the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var (used to help with HTTP Authentication) will only be set on requests that are routed through WordPress (including the homepage). And (on Apache<sup>***1**</sup>) the `REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var will *not* be generated when requests are rewritten to the WordPress front-controller (`index.php`), ie. page requests other than the homepage. Although I'm pretty sure that WordPress does not take advantage of this anyway. The `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var will not be set on requests to static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.) as it would have been before.

#### Two separate directives

With the two separate directives, as in the orginal code, the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var is set on every request, including requests for static resources. (But ordinarily, this is redundant.) And (on Apache<sup>***1**</sup>) the `REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var will be generated when requests are rewritten to the WordPress front-controller (`index.php`), ie. page requests other than the homepage.

(<sup>***1**</sup> As opposed to LiteSpeed, where env vars of the form `REDIRECT_...` are not generated anyway.)

---

> I moved the Wordpress block in my `.htaccess` file to the top and now my website is reachable.

That isn't necessarily the correct thing to do. Ordinarily, the WordPress code block (the front-controller) should appear later in the file. There may have just been a single conflicting rule that should have been "modified" or perhaps moved to *after* the WordPress code block. But moving those directives to after the WordPress code block may effectively "disable" those rules entirely.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Prior to me moving the "Wordpress" block to the top, this is what the
> first block had:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

That code block is just an erroneous "copy" of the WordPress code block (less the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` var) and should be deleted altogether!

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply. This is my first post on stackoverflow. Prior to me moving the "Wordpress" block to the top, this is what the first block had:: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @MikhailKoval Please edit your question to add that code in order to maintain the formatting. Unformatted code in comments (apart from being difficult to read) can also omit special characters, making the code meaningless.

Comment: @MikhailKoval That first block would seem to be just a "copy" of the standard WordPress code block with the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION var omitted!? You don't need both. (In fact, having both is arguably an error.) That should just be deleted altogether!

Comment: Question edited. Correct, the first block that was previously there is exactly the same as the Wordpress block except its missing this line `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` I will just remove that block altogether per your recommendation since the "wordpress block" already has that same logic plus that one extra line I need.

Comment: @MikhailKoval Yes, it should be removed altogether (it's not doing anything). I've updated my answer with that bit.